# Python Job Collector Files I/O

Tags: python, file, class, function, file-io

I am trying to make a program that you can input job names, categories, and pay, and i am trying to write the inputed job names, categories, and pay to a file to store the data, but i am having  problems doing so.

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, jobName = '', jobCategory = '', jobPay = ''):
        self.jobName = jobName
        self.jobCategory = jobCategory
        self.jobPay = jobPay

    def getName(self):
        self.jobName = input("What is the Job Title: ")

    def getCategory(self):
        self.jobCategory = input("What is the Job Category: ")

    def getPay(self):
        self.jobPay = input("What is the Job Pay: ")

    def displayJob(self):
        print("Job: " + self.jobName)
        print("Job Category: " + self.jobCategory)
        print("Job Pay: " + self.jobPay)
        print()


def Main():
    global NewJob
    NewJob = Job()
    NewJob.getName()
    NewJob.getCategory()
    NewJob.getPay()
    print()
    NewJob.displayJob()
    myFile = open('newFile.txt', 'w')
    myFile.write(NewJob.displayJob())
    myFile.close()

Main()
```

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: Also, Python is *not* Java nor C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayJob()` prints to stdout, not to your file. You have to return a string:

```
def displayJob(self):
    results = [
        "Job: " + self.jobName,
        "Job Category: " + self.jobCategory,
        "Job Pay: " + self.jobPay
    ]

    return "\n".join(results)
```

Or pass `file` as an argument, but that looks a little odd:

```
import sys

def displayJob(self, file=sys.stdout):
    print("Job: " + self.jobName, file=file)
    print("Job Category: " + self.jobCategory, file=file)
    print("Job Pay: " + self.jobPay, file=file)
    print(file=file)

...

NewJob.displayJob(myFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is nothing gets written to the file.  `Job.displayJob()` does not return anything to be written into the file, it only displays it to stdout. Figure out how you want your object to serialize to the file and have a method that returns that string.